# It seems scheduling not happen?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, kernel, schedule

I may misunderstand but it looks scheduling is not happening.
I created a Kernel module and created a Kernel thread in the module.

I expect "point-A" will be printed after scheduling since the monitor_main thread is set to TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE.

When I loaded the module, I saw the message "entry -- monitor_main" is printed.
But, I couldn't see "point-A" printed at all.
It seems I may miss something or misunderstand.
Can someone add some comment on this?
It will be very helpful!

Here is the code.

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kmod.h>
#include <linux/kthread.h>
#include <linux/time.h>
#include <linux/timer.h>
#include <linux/delay.h>

DECLARE_WAIT_QUEUE_HEAD(monitor_wait_q);
rwlock_t monitor_lock = RW_LOCK_UNLOCKED;
int monitor_event_id = 1;

int monitor_main(void)
{
   int event_id = 0;

   printk("entry -- monitor_main\n");
   DECLARE_WAITQUEUE(monitor_wait, current);
   daemonize("monitor_main");

   allow_signal(SIGKILL);
   add_wait_queue(&monitor_wait_q, &monitor_wait);

   for(;;)
   {
      set_current_state(TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE);
      schedule();
      printk("point-A\n");

      if (signal_pending(current))
      {
         break;
      }

      read_lock(&monitor_lock);
      if (monitor_event_id)
      {
         event_id = monitor_event_id;
         read_unlock(&monitor_lock);

         printk("event occurred\n");
      }
      else
      {
         read_unlock(&monitor_lock);
      }
   }

   set_current_state(TASK_RUNNING);
   remove_wait_queue(&monitor_wait_q, &monitor_wait);
   return 0;
}

static int __init init_activity_monitor(void)
{
   int ret;
   
   printk("Hello - init_activity_monitor\n");
   ret = kernel_thread(monitor_main, NULL, CLONE_FS | CLONE_FILES | CLONE_SIGHAND | SIGCHLD);
   if (ret < 0)
   {
      printk("failed to start kernel thread\n");
   }
   msleep(2);
   wake_up_interruptible(&monitor_wait_q);
   return 0;
}
module_init(init_activity_monitor);

static void __exit exit_activity_monitor(void)
{
   printk("Bye - exit_activity_monitor\n");
}
module_exit(exit_activity_monitor);
```

Comment: Calling `schedule` for a thread in TASK_INTERRUPTIBLE state puts the thread into the sleep. It should be noted in any example about low-level wait in the Linux kernel.

Comment: "I don't see soft lockup anymore." - If so, why haven't you remove that soft lockup from the **question post**?

Comment: On Stack Overflow we expect the question post to contain only a **problem**, not a *solution*. But your question post currently contains the code and the error message... which is actually NOT emitted by that code. This is very confusing for anyone who would read your post in the future. You could edit the code in the question to the state, which actually causes the error. You could even answer the question after that. Note however, that questions about "non-initialized variables" are not well-received here. See e.g. recent question on meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/416161.

Comment: Alternatively, if your new code code still doesn't resolve all you problems, you could change the problem statement in the question post. While "chameleon" questions are not well-received on Stack Overflow, changing a problem statement is allowed ... unless it invalidates existing answers.

Comment: I understand now. After schedule the thread is not going to be woken up automatically and needs wake_up explicitly. I added wake_up_interruptible at the end of init_activity_monitor().